# 508 compliant file upload in IE?

Tags: html, file-upload, accessibility, section508

I'm tasked with creating a 508 compliant form that includes a file upload function. It works just fine in any browser except for IE, but we need to support IE as well.

The problem is that the "Browse..." button on the file upload element won't open the file upload dialogue with the enter key. Instead, the enter key attempts to submit the form. The space key, however, opens the file upload dialogue just fine.

The code is super basic- a vanilla file upload element:

```
 <form name="submitForm" action=....>
      <fieldset>
           <%---other stuff here---%>     
           <input type="file" name="..." id="..." tabindex="12"/>       
      </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Comment: Consider that a user with that configuration may already know this. Consider that trying to code around that may actually confuse that user and make it hard to submit the form. Also, consider removing the `tabindex` and never, ever using a value greater than `0`.

Comment: If this is the case for the native file input in IE, users are likely to be used to using the space bar for this. The space bar is a perfectly good way to activate a button, I wouldn't try to mess with the browser behaviour

Comment: While I would LOVE to take a common sense approach to this, the design decision is out of my hands. The requirements for this specify that the enter key must work for this

Comment: The 'common sense' approach is the accessible approach. Keyboard users (including those using screenreaders and other assistive technologies) that prefer to use Internet Explorer are accustomed to specific key commands. Removing the enter key 'Submit' functionality from them and having it do something else is not a good solution. If your requirements are to make it accessible and you're asked to sacrifice the usability, accessibility and expected behaviour of the component I'd raise these concerns. Usability should be more important than design decisions.